# loop sound files in android?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

This code works fine on the initial loop.  However, once I stop and hit my loop button again, the files get mixed up and are played out of order.  Anyone have a clue what is wrong??  Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class OneExp extends ActionBarActivity {

private ListView lv; 
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
private MediaPlayer mp;
private MediaPlayer mp2;
int[] myAudio = {R.raw.e_1101, R.raw.e_1102, R.raw.e_1103, R.raw.e_1104, R.raw.e_1105,
        R.raw.e_1106, R.raw.e_1107, R.raw.e_1108, R.raw.e_1109, R.raw.e_1110, R.raw.e_1111};
int mCompleted = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.one_exp);

    Button btnLoop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (mp2 != null) {

                if (mp2.isPlaying()) {
                    mp2.stop();

                }
                mp2.reset();
                mp2.release();
                mp2 = null;
            }
            }
    });

    btnLoop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), myAudio[0]);
            mp2.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp2)
                {
                    mCompleted++;
                    mp2.reset();
                    if (mCompleted < myAudio.length) 
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(myAudio[mCompleted]);
                            if (afd != null) 
                            {
                                mp2.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                                afd.close();
                                mp2.prepare();
                                mp2.start();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) 
                        {
                           ex.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } 
                    else if (mCompleted>=myAudio.length) 
                    {
                        mCompleted =0;
                        try
                        {
                            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(myAudio[mCompleted]);
                            if (afd != null) 
                            {
                                mp2.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                                afd.close();
                                mp2.prepare();
                                mp2.start();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) 
                        {
                           ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mCompleted=0;
                         mp2.release();
                         mp2 = null;
                    }

                }
            });


            mp2.start();  

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setLooping(boolean

Why do you want to use so much code when you easily can use start(), stop(), pause() and setLooping(true) instead?

As far as I can see there is no need to check the lenght of your audio.

When you call pause() and later on just start(), your audio will continue where it was.

Call release/ reset only when you are completely done with the file.

Comment: I want to loop a series of files, not just one.  How can you set a loop of for example three files in a row and repeat all three until I push stop?

Comment: I would make a normal FOR() loop. If it's only 3 files, than they will stop at the same moment without any noticable delay.